# Applying system date in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I apply system date in my query?

```sql
SELECT L.NEVENTLOGIDN, LPAD (nuserid, 6, '0') nuserid, u.susername, 
       TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + ( (ndatetime) / (60 * 60 * 24)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
       date_time, l.nreaderidn, r.sname, 
       CASE 
          WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = 'LOCKER' and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('OUT') || '%') THEN 'OUT' 
          WHEN l.nreaderidn  IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = 'LOCKER' and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('IN') || '%') THEN 'IN' 
        END logtype 
FROM TB_EVENT_LOG l, TB_READER r, TB_USER u 
WHERE l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = 'LOCKER') 
  AND NDATETIME >= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-27' || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND ndatetime <= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-28' || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND l.nuserid = u.suserid 
  AND l.nreaderidn = r.nreaderidn                           
ORDER BY 2, 4
```

In this part I want to add the system date

```
>= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-27' || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') )
```

Base on what I search sysdate supposed to use at this but I'm struggling with the format.

I have try using this but still no luck.

```sql
SELECT L.NEVENTLOGIDN, LPAD (nuserid, 6, '0') nuserid, u.susername, 
       TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + ( (ndatetime) / (60 * 60 * 24)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
       date_time, l.nreaderidn, r.sname, 
       CASE 
         WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = 'LOCKER' and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('OUT') || '%') THEN 'OUT' 
         WHEN l.nreaderidn  IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = 'LOCKER' and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('IN') || '%') THEN 'IN' 
       END logtype 
FROM TB_EVENT_LOG l, TB_READER r, TB_USER u 
WHERE l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = 'LOCKER') 
  AND NDATETIME >= ((TO_DATE (sysdate || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND ndatetime <= ((TO_DATE (sysdate || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND l.nuserid = u.suserid 
  AND l.nreaderidn = r.nreaderidn                           
ORDER BY 2, 4
```

Comment: SYSDATE is already a date, and has a time component. When your write
NDATETIME >= ((TO_DATE (sysdate || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60
you can do it like this:
NDATETIME >= (sysdate- TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60

Comment: yes but i want only to get todays date plus 12:00:00 AM

Comment: if you want to use midnight instead of sysdate, replace by trunc(sysdate). If you hour X instead, use trunc(sysdate)+X/24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve  by using trunc funtion and sysdate

my final query is this

```
SELECT L.NEVENTLOGIDN, LPAD (nuserid, 6, '0') nuserid, u.susername, 
    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + ( (ndatetime) / (60 * 60 * 24)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    date_time, l.nreaderidn, r.sname, 
    CASE WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = cur_rec.SDESCRIPTION and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('OUT') || '%') THEN 'OUT' 
    WHEN l.nreaderidn  IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = cur_rec.SDESCRIPTION and upper(sname) like '%' || upper('IN') || '%') THEN 'IN' END logtype 
   FROM TB_EVENT_LOG l, TB_READER r, TB_USER u 
   WHERE 
   l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = cur_rec.SDESCRIPTION) 
   AND NDATETIME >= (trunc(sysdate -1) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
   AND ndatetime <= (trunc(sysdate) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
   AND l.nuserid = u.suserid 
   AND l.nreaderidn = r.nreaderidn                           
   ORDER BY 2, 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SYSDATE` is a function that returns `DATE` datatype, so you don't `TO_DATE` it. Simply use it as

```
where ndatetime < sysdate
```

(presuming that `ndatetime` column is also `DATE`).

Comment: ndate is a number thats why there is multiplication in it to get the exact date